# iOS SQLite: Insert statement fails, can't see why

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert

So I can create the database with no issue using the following statement for the first table:

```
     const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIBRARY_SEARCH (SEARCH_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SEARCH_TERM TEXT)";
```

But when I go to insert a row it fails. This is how I insert the row.

```
NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LIBRARY_SEARCH(SEARCH_TERM) VALUES (\"%@\")", myQuery] ;
```

Where myQuery is an NSString that holds the value of the searchBar.text in the app. It's a property and is of course synthesized.

So I then call this:

```
     if ( sqlite3_exec(searchSessionDB, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &insert_error) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Which fails. Can anyone see why?

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(searchSessionDB));` say?

Comment: It says "out of memory".

Comment: Think I might have it. Googled the error and I think I made a typo in my open database statement. Will check.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Made a small typo in my open database statement.

For anyone who looks at this in the future, this is how the opening statement now looks (and it works fine!):

```
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &searchSessionDB) = SQLITE_OK){
```

Thanks to Robert Ryan for suggesting this NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(searchSessionDB));
```

And thanks Elpsk and H2CO3 for the wrapper/app bundle information.

Comment: Two things: First, if you want sqlite to create the database if it's not found, then your syntax is fine. But if you want it to report an error if the database is not found, it's better to use `sqlite3_open_v2(dbpath, &searchSessionDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)` (assuming `dbpath` is a "`const char *`"). The standard sqlite3_open will create a database if it's not found. This won't.

Comment: Second, and this is going to sound strange, but make sure you "accept" your own answer, so this question will be removed from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Ah, nice tip about the sqlite3_open_v2. And yeah, I plan to accept it but it won't let me for two days. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you couldn't accept your own answer for two days, but I can imagine why. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for query your database.

It's a wrapper to **sqlite**, easy to use and easy and *all errors are explained better*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're trying to update an SQLite database located in your app bundle. You can't: you can't write to your app's own bundle. Copy the database file into the Documents or Library directory off of your app sandbox.

Other: if you're looking for an OO SQLite-wrapper, check out [mine](https://github.com/H2CO3/SQLHelper).

Comment: Excellent answer. With no offense to your OO wrapper, though, I have to second elpsk's suggestion to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Outstanding wrapper.

Comment: @RobertRyan No problem :) They're for different needs. My wrapper is for quick and convenient, simple manual DB access, not something "enterprise". :)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It was a silly typo that caused the issue now but I'll look into the App bundle issue.